# 2 = theta (1 + 1/n)^n ; why is a constant theta to e?

Tags: algorithm

This is for my Combinatorial Algorithms class. I kind of have an idea as to why a constant would equal e as but I'm a bit confused when I have the statement that 2 and (1 + 3/n)^n are theta of each other. This is pretty much saying that 2 and e^3 are theta of each other? Is it because they are both constants that we can say this? Or are we analyzing these two as n -> infinity?

Comment: Hi Ceelos, sounds like an interesting question but you might be looking for http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @MartyWallace indeed! I posted it there too, wanted to see if either side would help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a math problem, not a programming problem.  Also, your post is confusing.  It's not clear what you are asking.

However, you might find it useful to know that *e*, the base of natural logarithms, can be defined this way:

> *e* = lim<sub>*n*→∞</sub> (1 + 1/*n*)<sup>*n*</sup>

(See [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/e.html) for many other ways to define *e* not relevant to your question.)  Therefore, for the equation in your title, as *n*→∞, *θ*→2/*e*.

You can generalize the definition to powers of *e* like this:

> *e*<sup>*x*</sup> = lim<sub>*n*→∞</sub> (1 + *x*/*n*)<sup>*n*</sup>

(Check it with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+%281%2Bx%2Fn%29%5En+as+n+goes+to+infinity).)  Therefore, in the equation I infer from the text of your post, as *n*→∞, *θ*→2/*e*<sup>3</sup>.